# discord.py bot getting cooldown time remaining of command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a python based discord bot that has the following command

```
@client.command(name="Mine",
            description="Mine daily.",
            brief="Mine daily.",
            aliases=['mine', 'm'],
            pass_context=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def mine(ctx, arg):
   <content>
```

But when users hit the 30 second rate limit of the command it outputs the error to the python shell

```
Ignoring exception in command Mine
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\raner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
      packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
      yield from command.invoke(ctx)
   File "C:\Users\raner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
      packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 367, in invoke
      yield from self.prepare(ctx)
   File "C:\Users\raner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
      packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 351, in prepare
      raise CommandOnCooldown(bucket, retry_after)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandOnCooldown: You are on cooldown. Try 
again in 28.58s
```

What I want to do is have something that gets the remaining cooldown and puts it into something that can be said back to the user on discord e.g. 'This command is ratelimited, please try again in 28.58s'

I haven't been able to find much help for this online, and most of it is outdated or doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to write an [error handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) for your command that handles the [`CommandOnCooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandOnCooldown) error and sends the message.

```
@mine.error
async def mine_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        msg = 'This command is ratelimited, please try again in {:.2f}s'.format(error.retry_after)
        await ctx.send(msg)
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've put this command on the same level as my other commands, but doesn't output anything in chat or in the shell, although it does remove the original error message from the shell. Am I missing something else?

Comment: It needs to be after the `mine` command. Could you add a `print` in the handler to see if execution is making ti there?

Comment: The code works, but the output number is 20 decimal places long, is there any way to shorten this?

Comment: Sure, change `"{}"` to `"{:.nf}"`, where `n` is the number of decimal places you want.  I've edited my answer to have n=2